# How to make validation available for all digits not only first digit

Tags: regex, validation, angular, typescript

I have validation at my typeScript. I can validate between 0 and 9 successfully which does not allow me to press except numerical characters. That's fine but the problem is in the second digit it gives me error. The validation below is only find for the first digit. How I can make my validation to available for all inputs not only first digit?

```
'input2': [this.FormInput.input2,[
   Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern('[0-9]'), 
  ]
```

Comment: You could write a (regex) `pattern` that doesn't explicitly match only a single digit.

Comment: With latest version of angular you can write like this `Validators.pattern(/\d*/)` that allows 0 or more digits and `Validators.pattern(/\d+/)` to allow one or more digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `[0-9]+` to match one or more digits

```
'input2': [this.FormInput.input2,[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'), 
]
```